# Regex - Recursive Pattern

Tags: c#, regex, recursion

I have a string with same pattern like this:

```
../assets/
../../assets/
../../../assets/
```

I'm using regex to find the `../` pattern using:

```
(\.\./)
```

My purpose is to replace all the `../` become `root/`, and all the string above will become like this `root/assets/`

**Is there a way to do that with some kind recursive pattern with regex?**

---

**Update**

I'm using C#

```
string content1 = "../assets";
string content2 = "../../assets";
string content3 = "../../../assets";
string pattern1 = "(\.\./)";
string pattern2 = "(\.\./\.\./)";
string pattern3 = "(\.\./\.\./\.\./)";

// All the result is "root/assets"
content1 = Regex.Replace(content1, pattern1, "root/");
content2 = Regex.Replace(content2, pattern2, "root/");
content3 = Regex.Replace(content3, pattern3, "root/");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No recursion necessary, you can just do `s#(\.\./)+#root/#g` (You did not specify which language, so this is Ruby/Perl version): find any number of repeated `../` and replace the whole thing with `root/`.